# How to put one whole class to the right ? / how to add padding in class? - confused ( React.js - Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

So, I am a react js and bootstrap noob. Please help me by telling how can I achieve this desired change - Basically I want the Image ( which is seen on the right in the image below) to be put on the total right on my website, currently the text and image are a too close to each other. How can I do this?  below the image is also my code for that webpage.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OoTa.png

```
import React from "react";
import web from "../src/images/myimage.svg";
import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";


const Common =(props)  => {
    return (
         <>
          <section id = "header" className = "d-flex align-items-between  ">
          <div className = "container-fluid">
            <div className = 'row'>
                <div className = "col-10" mx-auto>
                  <div className ="row">  

                  
                  <div className = "col-md-6 pt-5 pt-lg-0 order-2 order-lg-1 d-flex justify-content-center flex-column">
                    <h1>{props.name} <strong className = "brand-name"> Pinnacle Tutorials</strong>
                    </h1>
                    <h2 className = "my-3">
                       We are a team of talented Teachers here for your ward
                     </h2>
                     <div ClassName = "mt-3">
                         <NavLink to={props.visit} className = "btn btn-success">Get Started check - {props.btname}</NavLink>
                     </div>

                  </div>
                  <div className = "col-lg-6   order-6 order-lg-5  header-img  d-flex justify-content-end">
                    <img src ={props.imgsrc} className = "img animated" alt = "home img "/>

                  </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
               </div>
              </div>  
          </section>
         </>

     
    );
};

export default Common;
```

NAVBAR CODE :

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";


const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <>
         <div className = "container-fullwidth nav_bg">
            <div className = 'row'>
                <div className = "col-12 mx-auto">

           
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light py-3 container-fluid">
  <NavLink className="navbar-brand" to="/">Pinnacle Tutorials</NavLink>

  <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul className="navbar-nav ms-auto">
      <li className="nav-item active">
        <NavLink activeClassName ="menu_active" exact className="nav-link" to="/">Home <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></NavLink>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item">
        <NavLink activeClassName ="menu_active" className="nav-link" to="/about">About</NavLink> 
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item">
        <NavLink activeClassName ="menu_active" className="nav-link" to="/service">Services</NavLink>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item">
        <NavLink activeClassName ="menu_active" className="nav-link" to="/contact">Contact</NavLink>
      </li>
      
      
    </ul>
   
  </div>
</nav>
     </div>
            </div>

         </div>
        </>
    );
};
export default Navbar
```

Answer (score 0):

So what's going on here is that you're creating two columns, each of equal width. If you want the column containing the image to place the image at the extreme end, I'd suggest doing it the flex way, i.e, giving the `col` containing the `<img>` a display of `flex` which can be given with the class `d-flex`, and then applying a `justify-content: flex-end;` to it, which can be done by adding the class name `justify-content-end`

At the end, your div should look something like this:

```
 <div className = "col-lg-6 order-6 order-lg-5 pad-10 header-img d-flex justify-content-end">
   <img src ={props.imgsrc} className = "img-fluid animated" alt = "home img "/>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, that seems to work but that also streches the image in order to fit to the end. Any idea how I can keep the size of image the same only?

Comment: Yes, remove the `img-fluid` class from the `img` tag. This class is applied to a div where you want the div to occupy the space of the parent div (kind of like how liquid / "fluid" takes the shape of a container its kept in)

Comment: Great! One last unrelated questiton to this post: One thing which is bothering me is how the navbar ends before it reaches the end. (plse see the imgur pic in my post) I looked around a lot but everyone says to use container-fluid to make it fit to end .. i tried but it doesn't seem to work .. it still stays the same. Can you please help ?

Comment: Try providing a fiddle / codesandbox so that I'll have more than an image to go off from.

Comment: I have added the whole navbar code also above, please check

Comment: Oh I get it now that you've updated the image. It's not occupying the width of the screen because you're using the class `col-10` in  `<div className = "col-10" mx-auto>` . Try making it `col-12` so that it occupies the full width. Also it should be noted that you've kept `mx-auto` as an attribute, bring it inside so that finally it looks like `<div className = "col-12 mx-auto" >`

Comment: Welp, now the image again went from the right corner back close to the text. I have updates both the codes up again, can you please check ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234255/discussion-between-areeb-khan-and-benzenec6h6).

Answer (score 0):

```css
p {
  padding-right: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-light d-flex justify-content-between">
    <div>Total Cost</div>
    <div>$50</div>
</div>
```